# How do I solve $\int \frac{1}{v(1+v^2)}dv$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve $y'=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ and I ended up with the integral $\int \frac{1}{v(1+v^2)}dv$ as part of the solution.

I got a big ugly solution using integration by parts, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{v(1 + v^2)} = \frac{(1 + v^2) - v^2}{v(1 + v^2)}$$

Now split the numerator.

Or try partial fraction decomposition to get the (simplified) result.

Comment: I love that technique!

Comment: I love it too , it's almost like a magic trick. :)

Answer (score 3):

Now use partial decomposition:

$$\int\frac{1}{v(1+v^2)}dv = \int[\frac{1}{v} - \frac{v}{1+v^2}]dv$$

$$=\ln|v|-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+v^2)+C$$

Comment: I always forget about partial decomposition!  Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

$$\log x -\log(1+x^2)/2$$

does it, I think.